# Unable to use classnames in typescript due to 'no compatible call signatures'

Tags: typescript

After running relevant `yarn add` commands, here are new lines in the `packages.json`:

```
"@types/classnames": "^2.2.7",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
```

Then I added these lines in my typescript files:

```
import * as classnames from 'classnames';
...
            <div className={classnames('normal', 'on')}>
```

Now I am getting this error

> Type error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ default: ClassNamesExport; }' has no compatible
>   call signatures.  TS2349

Content of my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `import * as X from 'x'`, you are getting a module namespace object. It is an immutable object and it is not callable.

Since `classnames` is a commonjs module, you need to set `esModuleInterop: true` in your `tsconfig.json` and do `import classnames from 'classnames'`,

or you can import it using the old syntax: `import classnames = require('classnames')`.

It is recommended to use `esModuleInterop`.

Answer (score 5):

Try to do it as-

`import classnames from 'classnames'`;

or

`import {default as classnames} from 'classnames'`;

If neither of them works, check if the package.json of the module you're trying to use has a 'main' or 'module' field. If it does'nt, that might explain the error.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer fixes my problem. Do you know why `import * as classnames from 'classnames'` does not work in my case? I created my app with `create-react-app`